live-build : E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye/updates Release' does not have a Release file
I I'm trying make an debian based distro using a tool called live-build on github actions running Ubuntu (for some reason i cant/not rather to build locally) and I get the error :

Reading package lists...

E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye/updates Release' does not have a Release file.

P: Begin unmounting filesystems...

P: Saving caches...

Reading package lists...

Building dependency tree...

Error: lb build command failed with code 0

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I have tried to change the mirros or some debootstrap releated options to fix this problem but they did not worked
Here is my build script (build.sh):

#!/bin/bash



# install required packages

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install live-build live-boot



# set configuration

LIVE_BOOT=LIVE_BOOT_OXIDE

DEBIAN_CODENAME=bullseye

DISTRO_NAME=OxideOS

DISTRO_HOSTNAME=Oxide

VERSION=1.0

BINARY_MIRROR=http://deb.debian.org/debian

SECURITY_MIRROR=http://security.debian.org/debian-security/



mkdir "$LIVE_BOOT"



sudo chown -R $USER:$USER "$LIVE_BOOT"

sudo chmod -R 755 "$LIVE_BOOT"



cd "$LIVE_BOOT"



echo "----- configure the live build -----"

sudo lb config -d $DEBIAN_CODENAME --debian-installer live --mode debian --mirror-binary $BINARY_MIRROR --mirror-binary-security $SECURITY_MIRROR --mirror-bootstrap $BINARY_MIRROR --mirror-chroot $BINARY_MIRROR --mirror-chroot-security $SECURITY_MIRROR --mirror-debian-installer $BINARY_MIRROR --debian-installer-distribution $DEBIAN_CODENAME --archive-areas "main contrib non-free" --iso-application "oxide live" --iso-publisher "Arshavir Mirzakhani"



if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

    echo "Error: lb config command failed with code $?"

    exit 1

fi



echo "----- build the live build -----"

sudo lb build



if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

    echo "Error: lb build command failed with code $?"

    exit 1

fi

And here is the project github link if needed
https://github.com/arshavirmirzakhani/oxide-linux

It may fail with apt-get update, because it's bullseye-security and not bullseye/updates: https://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/Release ...maybe the SECURITY_MIRROR config is non-sense.

@MartinZeitler I tried you suggestion about SECURITY_MIRROR but it's still the same thing

@MartinZeitler I think it must be related to lb config
